# Python going through links randomly in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

so here is my code

```
import random
import webbrowser

results = []
with open("al.txt") as inputfile:
   for line in inputfile:
         results.append(line.strip().split(','))

x = (random.choice(results))

webbrowser.open(x)
```

i tried to print out what's inside of the random and it's like this:

```
[["youtube.com"], ["google.com"]]
```

so i think the "[" key is causing this

i also tried to use it like this in another script

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(url)
```

it is working as expected so when i do

```
webbrowser.open(x)
```

it just recognize x as ["youtube.com"] or "["youtube.com"]"

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     results.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

`split` returns a list, so `appending` it to `results` gives you a list of list of strings, instead of a list of strings.

Use `extend` instead of `append`, so the list remains one dimensional.

```
     results.extend(line.strip().split(','))
```